# ActiveSync is not working with Exchange 2003 / Win Server 2003

Tags: exchange-2003, activesync

Trying to sync android / iOS devices and I'm getting "connection to server failed". On the iPhone the credentials get verified but when I try to get mail I get the above error.

Next thing I did was go to testexchangeconnectivity.com and the following test fails:

1. Validating the certificate name.
2. Attempting to test potential Autodiscover URL
3. Attempting to contact the Autodiscover service using the HTTP
   redirect method.
4. Attempting to contact the Autodiscover service using the DNS SRV
   redirect method.

Basically the SSL cert is showing up as the wrong name and I don't have any DNS records for autodiscovery.

I also noticed when I did the test I got EventID 3029 on the exchange server. I looked this event up and I got pointed to the following [MS KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/817379)

I don't want to go through all of those steps if the problem is something else completely. For what I understand mobile devices should still be able to connect with the SSL cert error and autodiscover not configured.

Any ideas on this one?

Comment: Check out testexchangeconnectivity.com as a tool provided by Microsoft to troubleshoot such things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Exchange Server 2003 doesn't use Autodiscover.
2. Run the connectivity analyzer by specifying the RPC over HTTP settings and see what the results are. It may come down to only the SSL error. If the SSL common (friendly) name doesn't match the URL then you'll need to address that, as the handdhelds in question may not have the functionallity to promt the user about the mismatch.
3. If the KB article does in fact address your problem then you'll have to go through those steps if you want to get it working. I had to do that with my Exchange 2003 server and it's really not that big of a deal.

Comment: I ended up doing the KB article and it almost fixed it. The cert error I have now is a whole new question.